# Compares integers instead of string in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, dom-events

I have a React app, basically what I want to do is, conditional statement in input. I type text in the input if its more than 5 characters; its going to say 'Its long enough' but it considers text as an integer value . When I type 6, it said long enough again.

Here is my components:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    userInput : ''
  }

inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
  this.setState({userInput: event.target.value})
}


 render(){

  return (
    <div className="App">
          <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.inputChangedHandler} 
          value={this.state.userInput}/>
          <p>{this.state.userInput}</p>
          <Validation inputLength = {this.state.userInput}/>
           
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

and I have a validation component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const validation = (props) => {


    let validationMessage = 'Text too short!';

    if(props.inputLength > 5){
        validationMessage= 'Text long enough!';
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
               <p>{validationMessage}</p>
            }
        </div>

    )
};

export default validation;
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: should be `inputLength = {this.state.userInput.length}`

Comment: totally missed that one...thanks for the answer. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have forgot to access the `.length` property of `this.state.userInput`.

Replace

```js
<Validation inputLength = {this.state.userInput}/>
```

with

```js
<Validation inputLength = {this.state.userInput.length}/>
```